# Prevent a file from downloading during for loop

Tags: c#

How can I prevent a pdf to download every time I call the function, for example during looping:

```
public void Get(string message)
{
   using (var webClient = new WebClient())
   {
      var pdf = webClient.DownloadData("http://google.com/something.pdf"); 
      // Do some process
      .....
   }
}
```

For example looping the function:

```
for(var i; i > 100; i++)
{
   Get("Help me");
}
```

Comment: WebClient (why WebClient instead of HttpClient?) caches your file so it shouldn't be (re)downloaded each time.

Comment: cant u just pass one nullable bool variable and download accordingly

Comment: So what you want to do in the loop then? Wait? Ignore the call? or what?

Comment: @Kev Fixx - You should think about accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you mean once, you could do this:

Make the variable `i` global, and the WebClient would only download if it is `0`:

**I have put the 2 options in multiline comments**

*Like @Adriano said, it is better to use a HttpClient*

```
int i; 

private byte[] cachedPdf;
public void Get(string message){
   /* if(i == 0){
        // do stuff
    } */
} 

public static void Main(string[] args){
    for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        /* if(i == 0){ 
                 Get("Hello world");
             } */
        // Do other stuff
    } 
}
```